# language-translator integration with Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, language-translation

We created **IBM Watson assistant** using dialog skill and created **language-translator** **API** using **Node js**. But we don't getting proper doc or example. Let us know how to to integrated with   IBM Watson assistant with ibm language-translator

```
app.post("/api/translate", async (req,res)=>{
try{
        const translateParams = {
           text: req.body.input,
           modelId: req.body.lang,
        };

            var message = "";
            const getData = await languageTranslator.translate(translateParams);
            res.json(getData["result"]["translations"][0].translation);
    }catch(err){
            res.send("sry error");
            console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Add details to your question. Also link to the docs you have already read and share how you integrated it so far. Are you using webhooks? Are you calling from Watson Assistant to the Language Translator or from your chat app?

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for reply . We are not used webhook for  translate.created node js application and created apis (https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator?code=node) http://localhost:3000/api/translate but i don;t how to use this localhost with customer UI (ibm watson assistent )

Comment: The docs for Watson Assistant have multiple sections dealing with webhooks and language translations. See here for a start: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-pre

Comment: Hi its not clear how your users will access your dialog, i.e. will users interact with your dialog via a bot on your web site, or another method like facebook messenger.  UNtil we have this info we cannot make recommendations. As an example if you use IBM's web chat bot client, you could call the IBM translate API from the client code, before the code forwards to message to the IBM orchestration layer. Or you could write your own orchestration layer that receives the message from the user, translates the message then calls the Watson assistant api to process your message.